# RegEx - check if string contains specific string fails?

Tags: regex, vbscript

```
abcVIRTUAL123   ^(?!.*VIRTUAL).*$^([a-zA-Z]{3})([a-zA-z0-9]{7})(\d{3})$ FALSE
abcVIRTUAL123   ^([a-zA-Z]{3})([a-zA-z0-9]{7})(\d{3})$                     TRUE
abcLOCATOR123   ^(?!.*VIRTUAL).*$^([a-zA-Z]{3})([a-zA-z0-9]{7})(\d{3})$ FALSE
abcLOCATOR123   ^([a-zA-Z]{3})([a-zA-z0-9]{7})(\d{3})$                     TRUE
```

Hi there, I'm new to REGEX and am using the VBScript library from with Excel.

In the above example I want to check if the string contains the word 'VIRTUAL' and if so return a false match.
I think its nearly there all except that the remainder of the pattern makes the string valid. 
Its ignoring my first negative look ahead.

I've tried various combinations from the forums but am stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Cheers
Nik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one: `^([a-zA-Z]{3})(?!VIRTUAL)[a-zA-Z]{7}\d{3}$`

Maybe better match this pattern `^([a-zA-Z]{3})VIRTUAL\d{3}$` and invert result?

Answer (score 1):

You've got `$^` in the middle of your regex which means "end of string, followed by start of string". Of course this can never match.

Try

```
^(?!.*VIRTUAL)([a-zA-Z]{3})([a-zA-z0-9]{7})(\d{3})$
```